# air for ios - sound

Tags: ios, air, for-loop

Good morning, I developed a simple soundboard app with AIR for iOS, but the sounds don't work. I mean, when I open the app I can see the buttons to push to play the relative sound, but when I push a button the sound doesn't play.

Here is my AS3:

```
import flash.text.TextField;

//Array for buttons instances.
var buttonsArray:Array = new Array();
buttonsArray[0] = a01;
buttonsArray[1] = a02;
buttonsArray[2] = a03;

//Array for the sound clip names.
var soundArray:Array = new Array();
soundArray[0] = 'media/a01.mp3';
soundArray[1] = 'media/a02.mp3';
soundArray[2] = 'media/a03.mp3';

//This adds the mouse click event to the buttons.
for(var i:uint = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++){
    buttonsArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked);
}

astop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopButtonClicked);


//This function stops any sound clip that is playing and
//plays the sound file thats clicked.

function buttonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();

    for(var i:uint = 0; i < buttonsArray.length; i++){
        if(e.target == buttonsArray[i]){
            var s:Sound = new Sound();
            s.load(new URLRequest(soundArray[i]));
            s.play();
        }
    }

}

//This function adds a stop button

function stopButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
}
```

I included the "media" folder in the "AIR for iOS settings...", but still doesn't work.
What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I just included the audio clips as .swc and everything worked fine.